# Can anyone identify what this smd component is?

Tags: filter, identification, components, surface-mount

[image]

It’s on a Pentax camera lens. I know it’s made by Murata. Believe there are six terminals.

Comment: My guess would be a ceramic resonator, probably associated with a microcontroller.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a 3MHz ceramic resonator. Probably just 3 leads (3 pairs of pads, with top and bottom connected together).

Similar one with a bit different form factor (from [here](https://www.enrgtech.co.uk/buy/product/ET16714093/CSTCW24M0X53-R0)):

[image]